# how to open a pdf file from a shared folder from a controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

how to open a pdf file that is placed inside a shared folder on my drive from a controller's ActionResult in MVC

Comment: what programming language and environment are we talking about?

Comment: Is there a specific reason the view can't just have a link to it?

Comment: c# and windows. sorry that i did not include that in my earlier question..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510451/how-to-return-pdf-to-browser-in-mvc). You'll also need to make sure the IIS process has permission to read from that directory.  Typically IIS runs under the Network Service account, but you should double check what account your App Pool is running as.