# With FileStreamResult, how is the MemoryStream closed?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, memorystream, filestreamresult

The following code works, but I'm wondering if the `MemoryStream` created is closed properly. How should this be performed or does `FileStreamResult` handle it for me?

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadBudgetedRoleOpportunities(
    Guid projectGuid, 
    IEnumerable<Guid> guidRequiredRoles)
{
    var rolebroker = new ProjectRoleBudgetBroker();
    var memstream = rolebroker.CreateBudgetedRoleOpportunies(
        projectGuid, 
        guidRequiredRoles);

    var fsr = new FileStreamResult ( memstream, "application/csv" )
              {
                FileDownloadName = "RoleOpportunities.csv"
              };
    // memstream.Close(); throws exception
    return fsr;
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `FileStreamResult` will do that for you. When in doubt always check the code, because the code never lies and since ASP.NET MVC is open source it's even more easy to view the code.

A quick search on Google for FileStreamResult.cs lets you verify that in the `WriteFile` method the stream is correctly disposed using the `using` statement. (no pun intended)

```
protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response) {
    // grab chunks of data and write to the output stream
    Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
    using (FileStream) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];

        while (true) {
            int bytesRead = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
            if (bytesRead == 0) {
                // no more data
                break;
            }

            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have access to source code, so you can check yourself ;-)

```
protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
{
  Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
  using (this.FileStream)
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while (true)
    {
      int count = this.FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
      if (count != 0)
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
      else
        break;
    }
  }
}
```