# Display PDF file from database in a popup window MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is an MVC3 application. I have numerous pdf files in a database and i want to retrieve them and display them in a popup window. I have my pdf file in a Stream object and I send it to the popup window from my controller like this:

```
 //This returns my model which contains a Stream 
 //object with the pdf retrieved from the database
   var model = GetPdf() ;

      //fileStream is of type Stream
       model.fileStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(model.fileStream, "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "download.pdf"
        };
```

But my popup window looks like[image: garbage]. Its gonna be displayed in a Telerik window, buti dont think that matters. How do i display a PDF file from a database in a popup window via MVC3? Thanks

Comment: Can you check the HTTP header the popup window receives?

Comment: [Possible duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510451/how-to-return-pdf-to-browser-in-mvc)