# In MVC, How to export table datas displayed in view based on a (filter value/ no filter) to a file(pdf, word, excell, csv)

Tags: c#, postgresql, model-view-controller, export

I am using Visual Studio 2012, MVC 4, postgresql, - building a web application.

Right now i am in need of exporting the table datas displayed based on filter value to any external file type(pdf, word, excell, csv).

I am using ajax pagination to display the records page wise(max 10 records per page).

question is how to get the specific data displayed in view to controller? if i could get this data, then i can finish this process of creating file with that data! based on links below.

though i could found creating word, pdf, excel, csv files with data in online mentioned in below link.
Excel file

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325103/MVC-Grid-to-Excel-file-download

word document

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra

pdf document

[How to return PDF to browser in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510451/how-to-return-pdf-to-browser-in-mvc)

kinldy help me for the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did for my above problem is, fetched the data from the db based on required condition, then using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; i writed the data in an excel file,  then the file is thrown to the user.