# How to save a image in pdf fileusing .net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code. i want to save the image in pdf file and how to save that pdf file in server map path or any location using .net mvc3

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

    PdfPage page = doc.Pages.Add();
    PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;
    string ImageFilePath = Server.MapPath("Chart.png");
    PdfImage pdfimage = PdfImage.FromFile(ImageFilePath);
    graphics.DrawImage(pdfimage, 10, 10);
```

Any one help me..

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw images to pdf file or how to save a pdf file ? If latter, you are asking it totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use iTextSharp to do it. You can refer to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779430/asp-net-mvc-how-to-get-view-to-generate-pdf) or there is a good guide [here](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1364-add-image-to-pdf-document-using-itextsharp.aspx)

Comment: Sorry it is not helped me.. i am using above code.. i save the image in pdf file.. then now need to save that pdf file.. what is the code to save the pdf file