# C# MVC website PDF file in stored in byte array, display in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am receiving a `byte[]` which contains a PDF.

I need to take the `byte[]` and display the PDF **in the browser**. 
I have found similar questions like this - [How to return PDF to browser in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510451/how-to-return-pdf-to-browser-in-mvc).
But, it opens the PDF in a PDF viewer, also I am getting an error saying the file couldn't be opened because it's - "not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged".

How can I open the PDF in the browser? My code so far looks like the following -

```
    public ActionResult DisplayPDF()
    {
        byte[] byteArray = GetPdfFromDB();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        stream.Flush(); 
        stream.Position = 0; 

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Labels.pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779430/asp-net-mvc-how-to-get-view-to-generate-pdf

Answer (score 13):

If you already have the byte[], you should use [`FileContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0), which "sends the contents of a binary file to the response". Only use `FileStreamResult` when you have a stream open.

```
public ActionResult DisplayPDF()
{
    byte[] byteArray = GetPdfFromDB();

    return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me. Using JavaScript to open a small window and call the controller I was able to use the above code to pull out a pdf image from the database.

window.open('GetInvoiceImage?ExternalImage=' + ExternalImage, 'Image_win', 'width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes');

Answer (score 12):

You can show the byte array PDF directly in your browser simply by using `MemoryStream` instead of `Stream` and `FileStreamResult` instead of `File`:

```
public ActionResult DisplayPDF()
{
    byte[] byteArray = GetPdfFromDB();
    using( MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pdfStream.Write(byteArray , 0,byteArray .Length);
        pdfStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Put that in a using clause!

Comment: @Rob MVC disposes of streams in fileresults for you, because you cant wrap it in a using clause (the stream will be disposed before MVC gets a chance to read it)

Comment: Use `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=Test.pdf");` to set the filename but not download the file immediately. You get `Response` for example by subclassing `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` when you have an MVC app.

Comment: inline + filename doesn’t seem to be a correct header. Chrome and Firefox respect the set username but Edge does not. So be careful and aware of that.