# Display ASP.NET generated pdf byte[] to web page without saving the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, mime

I'm using iTextSharp for generating a pdf. I can save the PDF file from the PDF byte[].

```
byte[] outputPDF = cnt.CreateBreakPDF();
File.WriteAllBytes(pdfOutPutPath, outputPDF);
```

What is the best way to display the output `byte[]` to a web page?

I want to show the PDF inside a div in my page. Not the PDF as a full response.

I've seen answers for MVC, but I'm using ASP.NET Web Application.

Is there a better way than using HTTP handlers to do so? I don't want to send all the details for creating PDF as query string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried [this in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNeAh/), and it works well in Chrome & FF,  need to check on other browsers as well.

Convert the `byte[]` to `Base64` using,

```
string base64PDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(outputPDF, 0, outputPDF.Length);
```

All I had to do is specify the `MIME type` as `data:application/pdf;base64,` in the source and give the `Base64` version of the `PDF`.

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64, JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyA..." type="application/pdf" width="160px">
    <embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyA..." type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

I couldn't be able to hide the top toolbar which appears in FF by appending `#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&statusbar=0`.

IE8 needs a saved pdf file to be displayed.

Comment: This works beautifully, but you do not need to wrap the `<embed>` in an `<object>`.

I just put `<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, <%: Model.base64doc %>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500"/>` and it worked perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck appending Open PDF Parameters to a base64 source?

Comment: I did not try to send any other parameters, but the PDF data itself as base64. But I think in the web browser, we can use the arraybuffer response of PDF stream and convert it to Uint8Array or blob and then use window.URL to create a browser link to display the PDF more easily in modern browsers.

Comment: I tried this and it worked both as an object and as an embed. My C# code was something like: byte[] bPDF = File.ReadAllBytes("filename.pdf"); 
string base64PDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bPDF, 0, bPDF.Length); wrapped in string str = "<embed src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + ...getPDFAsBase64() + "' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='800px' />"; My Razor code was <html><body> @Html.Raw(PDFModel.strReturnPDF()) </body></html>. It displayed the full height PDF, 51 pages.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", outputPDF.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(outputPDF);
```

Comment: @SenJacob you have not specified that in your question.Update it so you may get more answers

Answer (score 2):

I have being using `Convert.ToBase64String(content)` for some projects without any issue, until today with a 18 page file at about 1 MB. The error from Chrome's console is `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL`. I guess it's because of the string size?!

I ended up using web api and just return it as [`FileStreamResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289594/4271117) instead of Base64 string.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
await stream.WriteAsync(content, 0, content.Length);
stream.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
```

> Update: It's basically the same to display it on a razor page. I just copied my code for retrieving fax content using RingCentral here. And better yet, just use [`FileContentResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57525339/4271117) as you already have the `byte[]`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string messageId)
{
    try
    {
        using (var rc = new RingCentral.RestClient(setting.ClientId, setting.ClientSecret, setting.Production, "Fax"))
        {
            await rc.Authorize(setting.UserName, setting.Extension, setting.Password);
            var extension = rc.Restapi().Account().Extension();
            var outputPDF = await extension.MessageStore(messageId).Content(messageId).Get();

            return new FileContentResult(outputPDF, "application/pdf");
        }
        return Page();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed a good option in server part. 
Since the question is about how to display PDF on client page, could you please add how did you display it in client page?

Comment: @SenJacob Simply call the api and you'll see the pdf on page. I just figured out that it's the same to display on a razor page. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
<div>
<object data="myPDF.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="200" height="500">
alt : <a href="myPDF.pdf">myPDF.pdf</a>
</object>
</div>
```

You would just need to pass your pdf into the object data source.

Comment: Thank you, but as I asked in the question, I don't have a saved `PDF` file. I need to know whether I can embed the `PDF bytes` directly to the `object`. As we do with images like `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />`