# Display base64 string in aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to display the **base64** string in aspx page.
I am using the below code:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgNew = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
 imgNew.ImageUrl = string.Format("data:application/jpeg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToString(base64String));
```

this only works for the **base64string** for the **jpeg** formats. for the **base64string** of the **pdf** the image is not displaying properly. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base 64 to image and pdf in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328836/base-64-to-image-and-pdf-in-c-sharp)

Comment: [Try This One I'll think it will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108278/display-asp-net-generated-pdf-byte-to-web-page-without-saving-the-file)

Comment: Try this one it will help you and the sample code is given in link[code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108278/display-asp-net-generated-pdf-byte-to-web-page-without-saving-the-file)

Comment: Image control cannot display PDF file. Try to convert pdf to image. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60986d1b-2832-4413-8e8a-8290c196ffec/converting-pdf-file-to-an-jpeg-image?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: by using       
 `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", outputPDF.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(outputPDF);` I am able to see as a PDF . **But I am no aware of styling the PDF (need to border the contents)**

Comment: Do you want to display pdf in the img tag?!! or create download link?

Comment: Display display pdf in the img tag

Comment: you must use embed tag not img tag!! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the byte[] to Base64 using,

```
string base64PDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(outputPDF, 0, outputPDF.Length);
```

Comment: I have tried this method also still the image is not showing