# OkObjectResult with ContentTypes "application/pdf" some how is received by postman as 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, get, postman

With Postman, I am sending to my service a GET request with Header to Accept "application/pdf" and Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate, br, *".

On code side,

```
    byte[] pdf_test = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\somewhere\hello.pdf");
    OkObjectResult output = new OkObjectResult(pdf_test); // uncomment below once done.
    
    output.ContentTypes.Add(@"application/pdf"); // LINE IN QUESTION

    // And finally, back to the remote caller.
    return output;
```

When I debug this code, the status code is 200, and `ContentTypes` having "aplication/pdf". With Value having all the bytes of pdf.

When postman receives the response, I see the return code as 406 Not Acceptable.

The weird thing is, when I comment out the "LINE IN QUESTION" from above, the Postman receives message with 200 OK. But Content-Type accepted as "application/json".

Why is this occuring?

Postman ultimately does not matter but real program is expecting "application/pdf" content type, this real program does not exist yet. So at least I would like to get my side correctly done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return the content of a file, you'd better use a `FileStreamResult`.

```
var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\somewhere\hello.pdf");
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
```

---

The [`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult) is involved in content negotiation and formatting.
From the documentation:

> An ObjectResult that when executed performs content negotiation,
> formats the entity body, and will produce a Status200OK response if
> negotiation and formatting succeed.

This should not take place here to return a byte-array/stream.

The [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9f2d5273ea36c8d6243562f1aebe60bda4b80f1d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs#L122) shows that the `HTTP` status code `406 Not Acceptable` gets set when executing the `OkResultObject` since there's no formatter present (for content type `application/pdf`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. For my case, I needed to use byte array coming from elsewhere so FileContentResult was much fitting in this case, but basic concept is understood from your answer. (reference for FileContentResult  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524973/1076116)